# Swipable tags component on two lines

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement something like that:

[image]

where the user can swipe right and at some time the rest of the tags should continue on the second line but no more than 2 lines. I make the component swipable but all tags goes only on one line no matter how many of them I have. Here is my code:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                horizontal='true'
                style={styles.containerStyle}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.list}    
            >
                    <Tag />
                    <Tag />
                    <Tag />
                    <Tag />
                    <Tag />
            </ScrollView >
        );
    }

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        minHeight: 40,
        marginLeft: 8,
        marginRight: 8,
        maxHeight: 100,
    },
    list: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push `Tags` into `Array`.That array should be grouped.Yo can use review following code.

```
           render() {
                    return (
                         <ScrollView 
                                    horizontal='true'
                                    style={styles.containerStyle}
                                    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}>
                                    {this._renderTagGroups()}
                          </ScrollView>);
                      }
           _renderTagGroups(){

                    let tags=["marketing","reports","sales","servers","today",
                              "urgent","website"];

                    tags=this._chunk(tags, 5);

                    return tags.map((item,index)=>{
                           return (<Tag key={index}>{item}</Tag>);

                });
            }
            function chunk(arr, start, amount){
                var result = [], 
                    i, 
                    start = start || 0, 
                    amount = amount || 500, 
                    len = arr.length;

                do {
                    //console.log('appending ', start, '-', start + amount, 'of ', len, '.');
                    result.push(arr.slice(start, start+amount));
                    start += amount;

                } while (start< len);

                return result;
            };
```